# Is there any way I can keep my placeholder unchanged whenever I select an option on my react native element dropdown?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, drop-down-menu, dropdown

Im new to react native, I implemented a custom screen with multiple SelectCountry components representing different sections of my application, I want my drop down placeholder unchanged when an option is selected

```
const SelectCountryScreen = _props => {
    const [country, setCountry] = useState('');
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const label1 ="     Transaction"

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
            <Image source={require('../assets/hernzlogo.png')} style={{width: 150, height:150, resizeMode: 'contain'}}/>
        </View>
        <View style={{backgroundColor:'#FFF', padding: 10, borderRadius:15}}>
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name='typewriter' style={{position: 'relative', fontSize: 27, top: 38}}/>
            <SelectCountry
              style={styles.dropdown}
              selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
              placeholderStyle={styles.placeholderStyle}
              imageStyle={styles.imageStyle}
              inputSearchStyle={styles.inputSearchStyle}
              iconStyle={styles.iconStyle}
              maxHeight={200}
              data={local_data}
              valueField="value"
              labelField="lable"
              imageField="image"
              placeholder={label1}
              onChange={e => {
                if (e.value == 1){
                  navigation.navigate("Purchases")
                  
                };
                if (e.value == 2){
                  navigation.navigate("PointOfSale")
                };
                if (e.value == 3){
                  navigation.navigate("SalesMain")
                };
                if (e.value == 4){
                  navigation.navigate("Expenses")
                };
              }}
>           </SelectCountry>
```